# Python shiny: making interactive data viz linked to table in separate tab

Tags: python, python-3.x, shiny-reactivity, python-interactive, py-shiny

I’m still a beginner in Python so please keep things simple for my tiny brain.

So, I’m trying make an app which will show me the raw data of an uploaded file containing a dataframe as a table in one tab and a data viz based off of the data in a separate tab. Ideally with filters and drop down menus to select the data to display on the axes.

The part I really need help with, is to have a data viz (i.e scatter plot) using the plotly package with a two way relationship between the viz and the table displayed in the other tab.

For example, if I was to click on one of the data points on the plot, that would filter and be highlighted on the table in the other tab if I were to click back to it.

Any advice or direction on how to accomplish this would be great and very appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are two examples that, IMO, really cover what you want to achieve, provided by the posit team:

- The first example is a Data selection example where you select data points in a scatter plot, and it gets displayed in a table: https://shinylive.io/py/examples/#selecting-data
- The second one is a more advanced one, which selects and annotates the points with labels: https://github.com/posit-dev/py-shiny/tree/main/examples%2Fannotation-export

I hope these will assist you in achieving your goals.